# Dynamically change the image inside an imageview

Tags: android, image, timer, imageview

I need to show a certain number of images within a imageview dynamically, every few seconds, I need show in that imageview around 40 images, without onclick events or others, just go changing the image,  preferably obtain them from a website, how can I start with this?
really would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Handler to change the image each time delay you specify. Post a Runnable that changes the image with whatever time delay you wish.

Often people use an async-task for loading things online. I personally have never needed to, but you may need to load the images in an async task because it can slow up the UI and prompt a force-quit. Check on that though.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Bitmap bmp = MediaService.getDisplayImage("image_url", getApplicationContext());
    ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.yourimageviewid)).setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

in this way you can retrieve image from network and set into your ImageView... rest all shuffling images etc detail you can manage with using timer..

Comment: can expose an example of a timer applied to this type of need?  I've seen timers to do so, but no timer to get the URL of the image and display images every few minutes, thanks in advance.

Comment: at each tick of timer you have to basically 'update the image in your imageview' which is mentioned in above code snippet... show us what you have tried, and if you are facing any problem in it,then people here won't mind helping you out..